# R igraph - specify the minimum space in between vertices

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a way to set the minimum space in between two vertices in igraph so that the vertices don't look smashed together? The graph can be as big as needed.

Comment: How can the graph be as big as needed? It can be only as big as your graphics device, no?

Comment: Some good points here. @Gabor Csardi - I mean that the dimensions are not important - in can be very long horizontally and very short vertically, or vice versa. It will appear in a browser with a scroll bar. Usually igraph lays out vertices given dimensions for the graph. So to your point, I'd rather specify the minimum space between vertices, and have that determine size of the device, rather than vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

There might be, but an indirect way is to minimize the `vertex.size` and, if needed, `vertex.label.cex`. Making your device larger should then maximize space between nodes.

ex:

```
library(igraph)
my.graph <- graph.lattice(length = c(4,4), dim = 1, directed = FALSE)
plot(my.graph,
       layout = layout.grid,
       vertex.label=toupper(1:16),
       vertex.size = 20,
       vertex.shape = "square",
       vertex.color="white",
       vertex.frame.color= "black",
       vertex.label.color = "black",
       vertex.label.family = "sans",
       vertex.label.cex=1,
       edge.width=2,
       edge.color="black")
```

[image]